# Clojure: Find locations of "1" in a string and print out them in the format of intervals

Tags: algorithm, clojure

I'm tring to solve such a problem:

Given a string consisting of "1" and "0", find all the locations of "1", and print them in the format of intervals.

For example:
`"00101110101110" => 3, 5-7, 9, 11-13`

My (ugly) solution:

```
(defn bar [x]
  (letfn [(foo [mystr]
            (->>
              (map-indexed vector mystr)
              (filter #(= (second %) \1))
              (map (comp inc first))
              (partition-all 2 1)
              (filter #(= 2 (count %)))))]
    (let [y (map #(if (> (- (second %) (first %)) 1) (print (first %) ", " (second %) "-")) (foo x))]
      (print (ffirst y) "-" y (last (last (foo x)))))))
```

**Explanation:**

At first, I find the locations of "1" in the given string:

```
(->>
    (map-indexed vector mystr)
    (filter #(= (second %) \1))
    (map (comp inc first)))
```

`"00101110101110" => (3 5 6 7 9 11 12 13)`

Then, I partition the list of positions into a sequence of 2-element-tuples. If there is an 1-element-tuple at the end of that sequence, drop it:

```
  (->>
    (map-indexed vector mystr)
    (filter #(= (second %) \1))
    (map (comp inc first))
    (partition-all 2 1)
    (filter #(= 2 (count %))))
```

`"00101110101110" => ((3 5) (5 6) (6 7) (7 9) (9 11) (11 12) (12 13))`

At last, I print out the first position in the first tuple and the second one in the last tuple, while employing
`(map #(if (> (- (second %) (first %)) 1) (print (first %) ", " (second %) "-")) (foo x))` to get the middle part.

The input:
`(bar "00101110101110")`

The final result:
`3 ,  5 -nil - (nil nil 7 ,  9 -nil 9 ,  11 -nil nil nil nil) 13`

**My questions:**

1. How can I remove the `nil`s in the final result?
2. How can I solve this problem in a more concise way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to understand how to remove `nil`s from the final result, let's understand how they get in there in the first place. The value bound to name `y` in the last `let` form is actually a sequence of all `nil` values. The function `bar` itself also returns `nil`. This occurs because `print` always returns `nil` and `if` returns `nil` when the condition is false and the "else" form is not present. Effectively, every value in the sequence returned by `foo` is converted to a `nil`. Non-nil values in the output are values printed as a side effect. `nil` and non-nil values are mixed because `map` is lazy and the mapping function is applied only when the last `print` realizes the lazy sequence `y`. Needless to say, using `map` for side effects is a bad idea.

So the simplest way to remove `nil`s from the output is to avoid `nil` values altogether.

```
(->> "00101110101110"
  (map-indexed vector)                         ;; ([0 \0] [1 \0] [2 \1]...
  (partition-by second)                        ;; (([0 \0] [1 \0]) ([2 \1]) ([3 \0]) ([4 \1] [5 \1] [6 \1]) ...
  (filter #(= \1 (-> % first second)))         ;; (([2 \1]) ([4 \1] [5 \1] [6 \1])...
  (map #(map (comp inc first) %))              ;; ((3) (5 6 7) (9) (11 12 13))
  (map #(if (next %) [(first %) (last %)] %))  ;; ((3) [5 7] (9) [11 13])
  (map #(clojure.string/join "-" %))           ;; ("3" "5-7" "9" "11-13")
  (clojure.string/join ", "))
;; => "3, 5-7, 9, 11-13"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem kinda interesting, so I tried to attack it with the approach [from this talk](http://vimeo.com/6624203): Higher parallelism by mapping the data into a more convenient space and then in parallel combining sub-solutions. To that end, I focused on producing the intervals themselves in parallel; using transducers to perform all intermediate steps, then making an `eduction` and `fold`ing over that. This kind of organisation makes for a number of helper functions and such, so maybe not as good on the concision but hopefully interesting anyway.

I go through an intermediate representation as nested vectors: `[accepted boundary]`, where the interval represented by the 2-vector `boundary` grows until there is a discontinuity, in which case it is added to the end of `accepted`.

```
(defn indices "Transducer finding indices of an element occuring in a sequence"
  [element]
  (keep-indexed #(when (= element %2) %1)))

(defn combine "Combine two series of intervals"
  ([] [[] nil])
  ([[acc-a bnd-a] [acc-b bnd-b]]
   (let[ [[a b] [c d]] [bnd-a (first acc-b)] ]
     (if (<= b c (inc b))
       [(into acc-a (concat [[a d]] (pop acc-b) )) bnd-b]
       [(into acc-a (concat [bnd-a] acc-b)) bnd-b]))))

(defn plus "Add an interval to the series"
  ([] [[] nil])
  ([[accepted boundary] to-add]
   (if (nil? boundary)
     [accepted to-add]
    (let[[[a b] [c d]] [boundary to-add]]
      (if (<= b c (inc b))
        [accepted [a d]]
        [(conj accepted boundary) to-add])))))

(defn printable-indices [element the-seq]
  (let[glommed (clojure.core.reducers/fold combine plus (eduction (comp (indices \1) (map #(vector % %))) the-seq))
       fixed-up (conj (first glommed) (last glommed))] ;;Because the reduction is done, the last boundary is now accepted.
    (clojure.string/join ", " (map (fn [[a b]](if (= a b) (str a) (str a \- b)))) fixed-up)))
```